# How can I create visualizations in Spotfire that show the unique values of one column in multiple tables?

Tags: spotfire

I have 4 data tables, each joined from 2 database tables. All of them have a batch ID column, and all batch IDs have hundreds of corresponding rows.
I want to show which batch IDs are present in each of the 8 original data table, i.e. I want to create something like a SELECT DISTINCT(batchid) query for each table.

Ideally, I want to have a table where the rows contain all existing IDs and the colmns are the 8 tables. The cells would then contain a checkmark if the ID exists.

Another issue is that I have two different product lines (more are coming) which should be separated either visually or with property control.

Currently I have only managed to created 8 pivoted tables with a UniqueConcatenate function that gives me a list of IDs of each product, for each table. However, this is hard to read.

Should I create the SQL query right from the source table in the information designer instead of trying to manipulate the data in Spotifre?